# Need help removing JQuery from a web site

Tags: jquery

I've been tasked with removing some Javascript libraries from a website. I can't post the code here. Is there a tool or something that can point out the functions in the code that belong to JQuery.

The code is also using prototype. (One of the reason for removing jquery is to remove as asmuch external library references as possible and then settling on just one of them)

Comment: I doubt it. Read the source, replace the code line by line then test it to see if you broke anything.

Comment: why using multiple libraries?

Comment: multiple previous developers with preferences for different libs I guess

Comment: If it were me I'd be arguing for keeping the jQuery library. That could be one shit, thankless, minefield of a task. Good luck, hope library isn't being used too heavily used.

Comment: @cahz How much code are we talking about? (How many lines?)

Comment: @vinny - The only kind of task I get. :)

Comment: @Sime - estimated at a week .. so a fair bit of code. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JQuery is one of the better and most used libraries (which means potential for better community support). It's probably the one you want to keep.

I don't know of any tools that will help you identify JQuery calls, but you can search for `jquery` or `$`. Also, just remove the library reference, and let the debugger point out all the errors in the code. Most of them should be calls to JQuery.

To fix the code you'd obviously need to rewrite some functions you were using in JQuery, or find the alternative in the library you are still using.

Comment: People seem to be agreeing that this is the way to go. So I guess I better crack on.

Answer (score 1):

It will indeed be very hard to remove all the calls if you don't know which are using jquery.

I suggest this two options:

1. Remove jquery, and test your site, and check which functions are broken (very time consuming and prone to error, maybe use a crawler to do this). If you manage to find all the broken code, rewrite it in prototype.
2. Assuming jquery and prototype are running fine, but in case you decide to keep jquery, take a look at the `jQuery.noConflict();` this was created for situations like this, where two (or more) js libraries could "colide". Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

good luck!